How to round the borders of a QWebEngineView widget?
I'm trying to round the borders of a QWebEngineView widget, i have tried using stylesheet but the borders ain't changing.
Default:

I modified the borders on photoshop to demonstrate what we are trying to achieve:

#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QWebEngineView>
#include <QWebEngineScript>
#include <QWebEngineScriptCollection>
#include <QQuickWidget>

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    QWebEngineView* view = nullptr;
    Widget() : QWidget(nullptr)
    {
        QWidget* widget = new QWidget;
        widget->setObjectName("webEngineWidget");
        view = new QWebEngineView;
        view->setUrl(QUrl("https://www.google.com"));
        view->setAttribute(Qt::WA_StyledBackground);
        view->setContentsMargins(32, 32, 32, 32);
        view->page()->setBackgroundColor(Qt::transparent);
        QQuickWidget* quickWidget = view->findChild<QQuickWidget*>();
        quickWidget->setAttribute(Qt::WA_StyledBackground);
        quickWidget->setContentsMargins(32, 32, 32, 32);

        QGridLayout* layout = new QGridLayout(widget);
        layout->setContentsMargins(32, 32, 32, 32);
        layout->addWidget(view);

        QHBoxLayout* mainLayout = new QHBoxLayout(this);
        mainLayout->addWidget(widget);

        setStyleSheet(R"(
#webEngineWidget
{
    background-color: gray;
    border: 4px solid red;
    border-radius: 32px;
}

QWebEngineView
{
    background-color: green;
    border: 4px solid yellow;
    border-radius: 32px;
}

QWebEnginePage
{
    background-color: blue;
    border: 4px solid green;
    border-radius: 32px;
}

QQuickWidget
{
    background-color: yellow;
    border: 4px solid black;
    border-radius: 32px;
}
        )");
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}

This is a minimal example, the borders are just to illustrate what the stylesheet are changing.
What else we could try? the goal is to create the rounded widget to fit on our main window.

Have you read this page?

@Pamputt, yes, i tried setting the html background to transparent and also border-radius, but it continues the same thing.

@Pamputt That is completely irrelevant, as it's about injecting CSS into the web pages. Qt Style Sheets have absolutely nothing to do with that: they are related to standard CSS just for their syntax and logic, but they act on a completely different level.

I doubt this is doable with QSS, at least in the current implementation. You seem to be using the QQuickWidget support, while the common scenario uses QOpenGLWidget AFAIK; still, it doesn't make a lot of difference, as both widgets completely override their borders just by painting over the whole available widget area (within the contents margins, if set). The only option I can see here is to use setMask() with a rounded rect, with the major drawback of no antialiasing possibility at all.

Note that: 1. for the above reason, the QQuickWidget rule in the QSS is useless; 2. QSS only work on widgets, and QWebEnginePage is not a widget, meaning that any attempt in setting its properties is completely pointless.
